# Sorting in SSRS is not working as expected

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report with some columns. The main field is BillNo, and now I am sorting with the Bill no:

Then my report looks like below.

[image]

But I need it to look like this:

[image]

How is it possible?

Comment: Does it _always_ start with `POS/` or can it start with something else? You need to convert the second part to a number and sort by a number (not a string, as you are doing now) but you can only do that if you know for sure that you can remove non numeric bits.

Comment: yes it always starts with `pos/`

Answer (score 1):

This is my Initial Data before sorting.

[image]

Now when I sort it with ID you will see POS/3 before POS/10 and POS/12 and so on.

[image]

How did I achieved this?

[image]

Here is the expression I used

```
=CInt(Right(Fields!ID.Value,len(Fields!ID.Value)-4))
```

Note: In your case it will be `Fields!BillNo.Value` or something

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your sort order is based on the abc, so its goes first with the text and then from `0, ..., 9`. You can add the following expression to your sort criteria which will solve the problem:

```
'Sort order expression
'=CDbl(Split(Fields!BillNo.Value, "/")(1))
```